# not able to align two text views on the same line in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

The xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"  
  android:id="@+id/profileLayout">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Super Powers"  
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in Activity file i am trying to add one text feild whose value will change dynamically (value will be either ON or OFF) and that text should be inline with "Super Powers"

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
valueTV.setText("OFF");
valueTV.setId(5);
valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
```

can anybody tell me how to make two textViews inline?

Comment: Just remove this android:orientation="vertical" line from your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LinearLayout has vertical orientation. It should be horizontal to be able to place its children in the same line.

Comment: thanku Seraphis... its coming in same line now. and do you know how to make the text to align right hand side of the line?

Comment: I can see two aproaches: 1. set second `TextView` to `matchParent` and `gravity` (not `layout_gravity`) to right. 2. Change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and place it as you want from code.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the layout to 'relative layout', and then play with the XML

Answer (score 0):

Please change your orientation from **vertical** to **horizontal**. Now your textviews will be oriented horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for designing xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Super power"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and add your dynamic text view in LinearLayout  whoes id is "lin1"
hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Super Powers : "  
    />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt_on_off"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="OFF" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in your java file take the reference of ON OFF textview like this :

```
TextView txtOnOff;

txtOnOff=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_on_off);
txtOnOff.setText("ON");
```

thats all